# Vectorizing nested for-loops

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, for-loop, vectorization, osmnx

I have 2 for loops, which I would like to modify with vectorization, since the 2 for loops  take ages till they finish.

prerequisites:

```
import osmnx as ox
ox.config(use_cache=True, log_console=True)

# Create Graph of any city
place_name = "any city in the world" ### Enter your city
G = ox.graph_from_address(place_name, dist=2500, network_type="drive" )


and the dfGrid looks like this and has 2345 entries:
```

[image]

The code I want to transform:

```
for i in range(2345):
    for j in range(2345):
        if j == i:
            continue
        else:
            
            # From
            start = (dfGrid['Y_Centroid'].iloc[i], dfGrid['X_Centroid'].iloc[i])   

            # To
            end = (dfGrid['Y_Centroid'].iloc[j], dfGrid['X_Centroid'].iloc[j])  

            # Get the Nearest Node
            start_node = ox.get_nearest_node(G, start)
            end_node = ox.get_nearest_node(G, end)

            # Calculate the shortest path
            route = nx.shortest_path(G, start_node, end_node, 
            weight='travel_time')

            # Plot the route and street networks
            ox.plot_graph_route(G, route, route_linewidth=6, node_size=0, 
            bgcolor='k');
```

I heard numpy can be handy in this situation.

Comment: A couple of the lines in the inner loop can be moved to the outer loop if they don't involve `j`. For example: `start` and `start_node`. You might also think about assigning `dfGrid['Y_Centroid']` (and x) to a variable outside the loops rather than repeated looking it up.

Comment: i can put start and start_node after the first for-loop, you are right. The ```dfGrid['Y_Centroid']``` and (x) is constantly changing, so i dont want to assign them to variables

Comment: please provide a [mre] with input and output that can be tested against.

Comment: In any case, numpy won't help with plots. You may want to calculate everything, then plot after the calculations are done.

Comment: It is also not clear what happens in `shortest path`. This requires a [mre]

Comment: I tried to do it now, and ```shortest path``` calculates routes that minimize distance, travel time, elevation, etc

Answer (score 2):

Not every problem can be vectorized. Dijkstra's algorithm (for shortest path calculation) is an example of this. However, other parts of your code can be vectorized or otherwise made more efficient, and shortest path calculation can be *parallelized*.

1. Move all of your `iloc` code out of the for loops, as GeoPandas can take a list of values and select based on them.
2. Move your nearest node code out of the for loops, as the latest OSMnx (v1.1.0) has a vectorized `nearest_nodes` [function](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.distance.nearest_nodes).
3. Parallelize your shortest path solving, as demonstrated in the OSMnx [usage examples](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx-examples), and plot when everything is finished.

Comment: 1. Im still confused how that works, because i want to calculate shortest paths with each and every other points, then move to the next and and calculate them again from there and so on. Thats why i needed the iloc´s, how does that work in GeoPandas?

Comment: 2. What I want is to calculate all shortest paths to each and every node for that I always want 1 nearest node not all of the nearest nodes
3. I looked up your multiprocessing way too but it takes ages to finish it with only your code

Comment: 1) if you have a question about using pandas `iloc`, best to open a separate question. 2) the OSMnx [nearest_nodes](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/osmnx.html#osmnx.distance.nearest_nodes) function returns the one nearest node to either a single point or to each of several points. 3) shortest path solving is CPU-bound and cannot be vectorized. It can be parallelized across all your CPUs. If that's still too slow, you could rent more or faster CPUs (e.g., from AWS) or experiment with dumping your OSMnx graph to igraph for path-solving in C rather than Python (as shown in OSMnx examples).